# Newsletter com refresh ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Estou tentando fazer o envio desse formulário por ajax e não estou conseguindo, tem algo de errado? Estou batendo a cabeça nisso amais de 4 horas sem sucesso.

Obs: estou desenvolvendo via wordpress e estou utilizando um plugin chamado Newsletter para armazenar os emails capitados pelo formulario. Já consegui fazer funcionar uma vez, mas em outra estancia e em outro site, mas acabei perdendo o código que funciona e estou tentando novamente fazer funcionar.

```js
        var fmr = $('#formsnewslatetr');
        var dados = $('#formsnewslatetr').serialize();
        fmr.submit(function (e){
             e.preventDefault();

             $.ajax(
           {
               type: fmr.attr('method'),
               url: fmr.attr('action'),
               data: dados,
               success: function ( response )
               {
                   $('.success-box').fadeIn();
                   var retorno = 'true';
                   fmr.fadeOut();

                },
               error: function ( txt )
               {
                   alert( "ERRO" );
               }
           }
       );
});
```

```html
<form id="formsnewslatetr" method="post" action="/?na=s" onsubmit="return newsletter_check(this)" class="form-inline w-100">
    <div class="form-group w-100">
          <input class="i-email" type="email" name="ne" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="">
          <input class="b-email" type="submit" value="Assinar">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

O formulário está sendo submetido via botão `submit` passando pela função `newsletter_check(this)` que espera um `return`. Neste caso, se torna desnecessário o `fmr.submit` (até porque se ele estivesse na memória -- não está na memória porque parece estar dentro de uma função que ainda não foi executada --, o formulário seria enviado 2x: uma pelo botão `submit` e outra pelo `frm.submit`).

Neste caso é necessário ainda colocar um `return false;` no final da função para evitar que a página seja redirecionada.

Em vista disso, seu código deveria ter esta estrutura:

```
function newsletter_check(formulario){ // o parâmetro "formulário" apenas como exemplo
   var fmr = $('#formsnewslatetr');
   var dados = $('#formsnewslatetr').serialize();
   $.ajax({
      type: fmr.attr('method'),
      url: fmr.attr('action'),
      data: dados,
      success: function(response){
         $('.success-box').fadeIn();
         var retorno = 'true';
         fmr.fadeOut();
      },
      error: function(txt){
         alert( "ERRO" );
      }
   });
   return false;
}
```

Se quiser fazer algum tipo de validação do e-mail, basta colocar essa validação no início da função e se não for validado, adicionar `return false;` para que a função não entre no Ajax.